# Copy one file in my PC to another PC remotely

Tags: file, copy, psexec

I need a little script that can cause it, when the remote PC starts, it copies a file located on my PC. I tried with psexec but can not.
Thanks for your answers.

Comment: what operating system are the machines

Comment: Windows? What version? Linux? Mac OS X? Can you use something as easy as SCP or must it be something like CIFS shares?

Answer (score 0):

why not just use synchronize providing remote storage such as DropBox or UbuntuOne?